# how to activate the description in sql?

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER R_SERVICE_HISTORY_MESSAGE
AFTER INSERT ON SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAIL
FOR EACH ROW
AS IF(SELECT FINISHED FROM SERVICE_HISTORY, INSERTED
WHERE FINISHED=’T’
BEGIN 
PRINT ‘Hi <Full Customer Name>, your dog <dog-name> of breed: <breed-name> is ready for pick-up at Doggo Paradise Carindale’
END;
ELSE
IF(SELECT FINISHED FROM SERVICE_HISTORY, INSERTED
WHERE FINISHED=’F’
BEGIN 
PRINT ‘Hi <Full Customer Name>, your dog <dog-name> of breed: <breed-name> is not ready to be picked up yet.’
END;
/
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTYFq.png)
the table structure as follows, my trigger is totally wrong to activate after inserting or updating in SERVICE_HISTORY_DETAIL.and how to populate the description with name from other tables, I've tried so many times, am really confused about it. cheers

```
SERVICE_HISTORY              DOGS                CUSTOMERS
----------------------------------------------------------------------
MESSAGE varchar(300)         DOG_ID                C_ID
DOG_ID  
FINISHED                     C_ID                  NAME
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are asking?

Comment: @DerekBrown I‘ve update the picture description, thanks

Comment: mysql does not have an inserted table or a print verb and sql server does not have for each row so are you using sql server or mysql?

Comment: @P.Salmon  SQL Server

Comment: @spicy, SQL Server is a Microsoft product and does not have this trigger syntax. It Looks like Oracle to me so I'll remove the erroneous tags.

Comment: @Dan Guzman op does say 'am using sql server'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tested working example you can expand on

```
CREATE TRIGGER R_SERVICE_HISTORY_MESSAGE
ON SERVICE_HISTORY
AFTER INSERT,update
AS 
declare @cname varchar(100)
set @cname = (select concat(title,' ',firstname,' ',lastname) from dimcustomer join inserted on customerkey = inserted.cid)
IF exists(SELECT s.FINISHED FROM SERVICE_HISTORY s join INSERTED i on i.dog_id = s.dog_id WHERE s.FINISHED='T')
BEGIN 
PRINT concat('Hi ', 
 @cname, 
' your dog <dog-name> of breed: <breed-name> is ready for pick-up at Doggo Paradise Carindale')
END
ELSE
IF exists(SELECT s.FINISHED FROM SERVICE_HISTORY s join INSERTED i on i.dog_id = s.dog_id WHERE s.FINISHED='F')
BEGIN 
PRINT 'Hi <Full Customer Name>, your dog <dog-name> of breed: <breed-name> is not ready to be picked up yet.'
end
```